# Zeppelin: #{user} variable in spark.app.name not working in yarn cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-zeppelin

I'm running Zeppelin 0.8.1 and have configured it to submit Spark jobs to a Yarn 2.7.5 cluster, with interpreters both in cluster-mode (as in the AM is running on yarn, and not on driver host), and in client-mode.

I've set the config `spark.app.name` to `Zeppelin-#{user}`, which works in client mode. The application name becomes `Zeppelin-karbas` if my username is `karbas`.
But in cluster mode the name becomes `Zeppelin-#{user}`.

Any Ideas?

Comment: How are you setting `spark.app.name` ? In the interpreter config page?

Comment: @blackbishop I'm setting it in the interpreter.json config file.
it can still be seen/changed in the interpreter config page though.